# Is there any way to add Admob ad's in my website

Tags: admob, adsense

I want to ask the whole community in StackOverflow that is there any way to add AdMob ad in my website because I applied for my website is elececo.com

But they refuse my application for AdSense but my AdMob account is active right now so I want to ask that is there any way to add AdMob ads in my website, if there is any kind of way is available, I will accept

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible. AdMob serves in-app mobile ads, and is not intended to monetize web sites.

Comment: Is there any kind of script or anything that available that can apply on that website and apply ad unit ID by doing this can I show ad

Comment: As the answer stated, website ads are not something you'd implement with admob.

Answer (score -1):

yes it will be many way to add the admob ads in website.But it will be only visible on mobile View. It will be work properly....

you can refer this [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b5a9HZIuTNk)